# How can I restrict the client to seeing only the latest 100 records?

Tags: meteor

I have a file called `server/publications.js` with the following:

```
var MAX_RESULTS = 100;

Meteor.publish('messages', function () {
  var count = Messages.find().count();
  if (count > MAX_RESULTS) {
    return Messages.find({}, {sort: {submitted: 1}, skip: count - MAX_RESULTS});
  } else {
    return Messages.find();
  }
});
```

And a file called `client/main.js` with:

```
Meteor.subscribe('messages');
```

In my template helpers I then simply call `Messages.find()`. This technique works by giving the client only the latest 100 results *at the start*. With each new record, though, the client sees more and more.

How can I make it so that client *only* sees the latest 100 results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [limit](http://docs.meteor.com/#find):

```
Messages.find({}, {sort: {submitted: 1},
                   skip: count - MAX_RESULTS, 
                   limit: MAX_RESULTS
});
```

Comment: Hmm, trying this and it seems that now when I try to insert a message, the client never receives it. If I refresh the page it works, though. Is there a better way to get the *last* 100 messages?

Comment: you could remove the `skip` and use `sort:{submitted:-1}`

Comment: That's probably a good idea. But I need my messages sorted that way so the page renders them in the correct order. Is there a way to reverse the `{{#each}}`?

Comment: EDIT: I figured it out :) I'll sort "backwards" on the server, limiting to 100. Then on the client, I'll get only 100 records and sort those the correct way!